# Elasticsearch function_score query on a nested array

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create a query with a field_value_factor query to increase the score of a document based on the values of some (matched) nested array elements.

It should filter the nested array elements based on a match query and then run the field_value_factor function for every matched element.

Here is what I have so far:

Index mappings:

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "skills": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "level": {
            "type": "short"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some documents:

```json
[{
  "name": "Alice",
  "skills": [ { "id": "aws ecs", "level": 1 },
              { "id": "aws vpc", "level": 2 }]
},{
  "name": "Bob",
  "skills": [ { "id": "aws ecs", "level": 3 },
              { "id": "aws vpc", "level": 4 }]
},{
  "name": "Elli",
  "skills": [ { "id": "aws ecs", "level": 7 },
              { "id": "aws vpc", "level": 60}, 
              { "id": "aws ecr", "level": 1 },
              { "id": "java",    "level": 100 }]
}]
```

Now, let's say we want to find the person with the highest aws skills in total. It should be Elly because they have a total of (7+60+1) combined experience if we search for 'aws'.

My query for this is:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "skills",
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          }, 
          "functions": [
            {
              "field_value_factor": {
                "field": "skills.level",
                "factor": 1,
                "missing": 0.1
              },
              "filter": {
                "match": {
                  "skills.id": "aws"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "explain": true
}
```

I wrap my function_score in a nested query to run it for all of the peoples skills (so i think). Then i run the field_value_factor function on all skills matching 'aws' (so i think).

The result of the query looks good at first glance, Elly is the first result. But when i take a look at the query explanation, i can see that the function_score query only returns a score of 60 but i was expecting the score to be the sum of all matching 'aws' skills of Elly (7+60+1)=68.

It seems like the field_value_factor function only ran for the skill with the highest value. First i thought it could be something with the nesting and at the time of the function execution the result of the filter is a flattened array of all matching skills and the function only takes the first (according to the documentation) but after playing around with the skill values of Elly i can confirm that the function always takes Elly's highest matching skill (maybe some internal sorting?).

I tried a lot of different queries but none of them seem to work they way i need it.

Any help on this is gratefully appreciated. I am also open for different approaches, maybe someone has an idea how to accomplish this in a different way or knows some documentation about best practices, i found nothing so far :/

Answer (score 0):

Try such query

```
GET /skills/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
  "aggs": {
    "by_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "inside_skills": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "skills"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filter_out": {
              "filter": {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                  "skills.id": {
                    "query": "aws*"
                  }
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "level_sum": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "skills.level"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "sort_by_level_sum": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "inside_skills>filter_out>level_sum": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "by_name" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Elli",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "inside_skills" : {
            "doc_count" : 4,
            "filter_out" : {
              "doc_count" : 3,
              "level_sum" : {
                "value" : 68.0
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Bob",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "inside_skills" : {
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "filter_out" : {
              "doc_count" : 2,
              "level_sum" : {
                "value" : 7.0
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Alice",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "inside_skills" : {
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "filter_out" : {
              "doc_count" : 2,
              "level_sum" : {
                "value" : 3.0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can filter only highest level sum name by the `"size": 1` line in `bucket_sort`